# How to create a dataframe from a dictionary such that each entry is a list?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a dataframe from a dictionary where each entry is a list? For example, the script below

```
for k,v in pose.items():
    print(k,v)
```

prints

```
p1_center_head [-0.91411722 -1.11261988  1.70305252]
p1_right_hand [-0.6696707  -1.45284259  0.85303462]
p1_front_chest [-0.90311265 -1.15465713  1.09575438]
p1_right_shoulder [-0.88741797 -1.37508869  1.49578547]
p1_right_elbow [-0.8592056  -1.48356283  1.14748859]
p1_right_head [-0.92714155 -1.27181339  1.6833576 ]
p1_left_shoulder [-1.14574909 -1.15120935  1.48121977]
p1_left_head [-1.06484675 -1.14306569  1.65506554]
p2_center_head [1.0070374  1.08997941 1.69709778]
p1_right_wrist [-0.72482365 -1.47362924  0.92447436]
p2_right_shoulder [0.95422077 1.31905603 1.48511732]
p2_right_hand [0.69995475 1.25936687 0.90006113]
p2_right_wrist [0.75100577 1.30776393 0.94339645]
p2_left_shoulder [1.24170136 1.11059046 1.47705841]
p2_back_chest [1.19639254 1.35239506 0.93713373]
p1_back_chest [-1.06148314 -1.38686275  1.03079486]
p2_front_chest [0.9896763  1.14398277 0.99924839]
p2_right_elbow [0.88454074 1.43418157 1.13609421]
p2_right_head [1.01738358 1.24647975 1.68129683]
p2_left_head [1.15873718 1.12672687 1.66546488]
```

When I create a dataframe and save it to a csv file however, each entry contains one float instead of a list of floats.

```
pose = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pose)
pose.to_csv("pose.csv"),index=False)
```

I need each entry to be a list e.g. `pose["p1_center_head"] = [-0.91411722 -1.11261988  1.70305252]`

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pose, orient="index")
df['list_item'] = df.apply(list, axis=1)
df.drop(columns=[0, 1, 2], inplace=True)
print(df)
    
Output:

                                                 list_item    
p1_center_head      [-0.91411722, -1.11261988, 1.70305252]
p1_right_hand        [-0.6696707, -1.45284259, 0.85303462]
p1_front_chest      [-0.90311265, -1.15465713, 1.09575438]
p1_right_shoulder   [-0.88741797, -1.37508869, 1.49578547]
p1_right_elbow       [-0.8592056, -1.48356283, 1.14748859]
p1_right_head        [-0.92714155, -1.27181339, 1.6833576]
p1_left_shoulder    [-1.14574909, -1.15120935, 1.48121977]
p1_left_head        [-1.06484675, -1.14306569, 1.65506554]
p2_center_head         [1.0070374, 1.08997941, 1.69709778]
p1_right_wrist      [-0.72482365, -1.47362924, 0.92447436]
p2_right_shoulder     [0.95422077, 1.31905603, 1.48511732]
p2_right_hand         [0.69995475, 1.25936687, 0.90006113]
p2_right_wrist        [0.75100577, 1.30776393, 0.94339645]
p2_left_shoulder      [1.24170136, 1.11059046, 1.47705841]
p2_back_chest         [1.19639254, 1.35239506, 0.93713373]
p1_back_chest       [-1.06148314, -1.38686275, 1.03079486]
p2_front_chest         [0.9896763, 1.14398277, 0.99924839]
p2_right_elbow        [0.88454074, 1.43418157, 1.13609421]
p2_right_head         [1.01738358, 1.24647975, 1.68129683]
p2_left_head          [1.15873718, 1.12672687, 1.66546488]
```

Then you can further query for an entry like this:

```
df.loc['p1_right_head']

Output:

list_item    [-0.92714155, -1.27181339, 1.6833576]
Name: p1_right_head, dtype: object
```